# Garbage value while incrementing a void*

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

This code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
   void *ptr;
   int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
   ptr = arr;
   ptr++;
   printf("%d",*(int*)ptr);
}
```

Prints some garbage value but I was expecting it to print `2`. Why doesn't it print `2`?

Comment: Don't you get a compile-error on the line `ptr++` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some C compilers treat void pointer arithmetic as they do char*. It's invalid in C++.

No matter, you really should only be incrementing non void pointers since pointer arithmetic relies on knowledge of the size and alignment of the data type.

Comment: "C treats void pointer arithmetic as it does char*" - well, some compilers do this for historical reasons, but it's contentious whether it's valid C or not.

Comment: @detly yes I can see my answer was imprecise. I find it hard to get excited by the detail of void pointer arithmetic since it is so obviously a bad idea.

Comment: you mean resolving several ambiguous sub-clauses of the C standard for purely academic reasons **isn't** the highlight of your day?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am late here. First off, great answer. Would like to ask: but his `*ptr` is then assigned to point to the first location of the array which is of type `int`, so he was not incrementing the `void *`, right? Thanks.

Comment: @Unheilig it is the type of the variable that is incremented that determines what the increment means.

Answer (score 5):

You can't perform pointer arithmetic on a void pointer  because the compiler doesn't have any idea about the size of the pointed to objects.

Your code doesn't get compiled on comeau online. Its another evil gcc extension I guess.

Comment: I think gcc treats `void*` as `char*` when performing arithmetic.

Comment: @GMan (and @Prasoon) - there's a bit of info here: [Pet Peeves: People who try to increment void pointers](http://talideon.com/weblog/2007/10/no-inc-voidp.cfm); see also the [GCC documentation on it](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.0/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html#Pointer-Arith).

Comment: The C standard does not mention pointer arithmetics on void pointers. I think that the only thing you can read in the standard is that void pointers should be implemented identically to char pointers in terms of size and alignment.

Answer (score -2):

try

```
int *ptr
```

ptr++ increments by size of int in this case

Comment: your statement is incorrect-(ptr++ increments by 4).the correct statement should be (ptr++ increments by size of an int)